# Importing Bootstrap 4 variables.scss breaks Angular 6 compilation

Tags: angular, sass, bootstrap-4

An Angular CLI app has its scss files structured the following way:

The folder located at `/src/scss/` contains:

**bootstrap.partials.scss**

```
// Bootstrap partial imports to keep the bloat away
@import '~bootstrap/scss/functions';
@import '~bootstrap/scss/variables';
@import '~bootstrap/scss/mixins';
@import '~bootstrap/scss/reboot';
@import '~bootstrap/scss/type';
@import '~bootstrap/scss/images';
@import '~bootstrap/scss/grid';
@import '~bootstrap/scss/utilities';
@import '~bootstrap/scss/buttons';
@import '~bootstrap/scss/transitions';
@import '~bootstrap/scss/modal';
@import '~bootstrap/scss/close';
@import '~bootstrap/scss/nav';
@import '~bootstrap/scss/navbar';
```

**theme.scss**

```
// This is a set of internal bootstrap variables overrides
@import 'variables';

$font-family-sans-serif:  some-custom-font, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
$font-family-monospace:   Menlo, Monaco, Consolas, "Courier New", monospace;
$font-family-base:        $font-family-sans-serif;

$body-bg:                 #fff;

$modal-transition:        transform .1s ease-out !default;
```

**variables.scss**

```
$brand-primary: #621f37;
$brand-success: #23a023;
$brand-info: #5bc0de;
$brand-warning: #f0ad4e;
$brand-danger: #d9534f;
```

**styles.scss** at `/src/`

```
@import 'scss/variables';
@import 'scss/theme';
@import 'scss/bootstrap.partials';
@import '~bootstrap/scss/_variables.scss';
@import '~bootstrap/scss/_mixins.scss';

// Buttons
.btn-custom-inverted {
  @include button-variant(white, $brand-primary);
  color: $brand-primary !important;
}

.btn-custom {
  @include button-variant($brand-primary, white);
  color: white !important;
}

.custom {
  color: $brand-primary !important;
}

.bg-custom {
  background-color: $brand-primary !important;
  color: white;
}
```

**angular.json** contains at this path
`projects/[project-name]/architect/build/options`

```
"stylePreprocessorOptions": {
  "includePaths": [
    "src/scss"
  ]
}
```

Now - the problem follows.

Whenever I try to `@import '~bootstrap/scss/_variables.scss';` from within a component's scss file, the compilation breaks and I am getting errors that usually point to `@link-hover-color`:

```
ERROR in ./src/app/home/containers/home-locations/home-locations.component.scss
Module build failed: 
$link-hover-color:          darken($link-color, 15%) !default;
                           ^
      Argument `$color` of `darken($color, $amount)` must be a color
      in /Users/.../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_variables.scss (line 170, column 29)
```

which is kind of irrelevant per se (apparently `$link-color` is not a color for some reason), but I don't understand why it breaks.

Questions:

1. How can I ensure I can use bootstrap import multiple times?
2. How can I make sure multiple imports will only access the values but not import the referenced stylesheets multiple times?